# Completed PDF Form not Visible on Other Computer

Tags: mac, pdf, evince

I filled out a form for my supervisor using Evince in Ubuntu 14.04 but she can't see my (typed) signature line and date. I can see it fine in both Evince and the Gmail viewer. She is using Adobe Professional on a Mac. Is there other software (not including graphics editors) that I could use that would be more likely to be compatible?

Comment: Okular, perhaps.

Comment: There's no free (in either sense) pdf solution that can properly fill out pdf forms in linux, certainly nothing that's compatible with actual Adobe.